# Shapado: running on MySQL or PostgreSQL?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, shapado

I am interested in using [Shapado](https://github.com/ricodigo/shapado) to create a Q&A site on Ruby on Rails. But it uses MongoDB as database; how can I change it to run on MySQL or PostgreSQL?

Comment: You'd almost certainly have to a near-rewrite on your hands, sorry.

Comment: Can you outline why you don't want to run on MongoDB? I'd think it would make more sense to use what already is working and tested. If you need to join the data to tables in a relational database, then write a copy system that periodically dumps MongoDB data into MySQL - much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rewrite each and every model to inherit from ActiveRecord::Base. Rewrite the fields to a migration and recreate the data model that way.

This is not an easy deal.